# Android OpenGL help needed

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I've to make a media player in android which uses OpenGl for 3D graphics....These graphics could be the same as used in Windows Media PLayer background etc. I'm new to OpenGL...
  Can you please suggest some tutorials or the approach that i should follow for the same. .. An example using OpenGL in Android wwould be appreciated....
  Thank you in advance....

Comment: What is going on with all the periods?!

Comment: @unwind Its that time of the month.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Beside the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html), you will find some tutorial out there.

- [OpenGL ES Tutorial for Android – Part I – Setting up the view](http://blog.jayway.com/2009/12/03/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android-part-i/)
- [rest of OpenGL ES series](http://blog.jayway.com/tag/opengl-es/)
- [Android 3D game tutorial – Part I](http://www.droidnova.com/android-3d-game-tutorial-part-i,312.html)
- [Android 2D/3D Graphics - OpenGL Tutorials](http://www.anddev.org/viewforum.php?f=2)

However, that may not address *exactly* the kind of usage you are after.

[Martin Erhardt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1248398/martin-erhardt) adds:

- [**Learn Open GL ES**](http://www.learnopengles.com/), which contains many tutorials on OpenGL ES 2.0 [and Android](http://www.learnopengles.com/category/android-tutorials/).

Comment: @Rohan: my limited experience with OpenGL isn't enough to properly answer your second question.

Comment: I'd like to add these tutorials which deals with OGL ES 2.0: http://www.learnopengles.com/