# 2D example with OpenGL

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am looking for a very simple tutorial to use OpenGL only for 2D drawing.

My problem is that I want to draw, with OpenGl a bitmap having its pixels.

Thank you in advance,
Ouael

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android OpenGL help needed.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572470/android-opengl-help-needed)

Answer (score 2):

The [glbuffer](http://github.com/richq/glbuffer) for the Android NDK was useful for me.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572470/android-opengl-help-needed/3572530#3572530) also has many tutorials linked.

Answer (score -4):

Get any 3d example and just set the z coordinate to zero.
e.g. if you have coordinates like (2,3,1) change it to (2,3) or (2,3,0).